# How can I listen for keyboard input? such as arrow keys?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

what is the easiest way to listen for key presses from the user? Specifically I am writing an image viewer program that uses a JFileChooser to select images and on the left side, a JList that shows the contents of the director. I would like to make the arrow kets (left/right) move to the next/previous file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a [KeyListener](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).  The linked tutorial also talks about focus, which will be important to ensure your key events are trapped by the right handler.

Comment: okay, so I need to give my window focus or my imageIcon where I am displaying my image? Or should I switch it to a Graphic and give that focus? I am confused..

Comment: You need to give focus to whatever component has the action listener attached to it that you want to be invoked by a keypress.  The key bindings approach suggested in another answer might be fruitful in this regard too if you can work what you what to do into that idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Swing was designed to use [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

In fact a JList already supports the up/down keys to move to the next item in the list. You can easily map these Actions to the left/right keys.